# How to access a system with write permission after file system check fails?

Tags: centos, shell, boot, hard-drive, fsck

I created three new partitions, but after a reboot, the system is being dropped to a shell:

```
/dev/mapper/group-newpartition: clean, 11/655360 files, 276620/2621440 blocks [FAILED]

An error occurred during the file system check.
Dropping you to a shell; the system will reboot
Give root password for maintenance.
```

I tried to fix the disk error with `fsck()`, but the result status code is 0x4. I tried to reverse what I changed in `/etc/fstab` so that the system didn't check the partition while booting. But the shell the system being dropped to was a read only file system. I tried to access through the single user mode, but the result was the same. How to fix the problem?

Comment: Why would you consider attempting to modify a seriously damaged disk that failed an fsck?

Comment: This downvote because you asked a question, didn't even made it ready (see the end), and then disappeared without any reaction. You let others work for nothing.

Comment: I check the post when I am available online. I asked 16 hours ago. And revisit the post is the first thing I do this morning when I am before a computer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are in read-only mode is that:
a) Your file system was found to be damaged, then
b) Your OS tried to fix it at boot, but failed, so
c) Dropped you into a read-only shell so that you can extract and backup your files without modifying original file system hence preventing you from damaging it further.

If I were you, I would try to fix the problem first. However, if you do insist, you can remount your filesystem with `-o loop,rw` like

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt/sysimage -o loop,rw
```

where `/mnt/sysimage` is your mount point.